# restriction operators and continuous maps from Hom(X,Y) to Hom(A,Y)

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, algebraic-topology

I am trying to solve this topological question and would like to know if I am on the right track with my solution. As in if I have the correct answer or if I need to add or delete anything. However, I think I do have the correct answer.

Question:
[image]

Answer:
[image]